# Prove that given $c^Tx=d$ for all x such that $Ax=b$ iff there is a vector $\lambda$ such that $c=A^T\lambda,d=b^T\lambda$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Given the prompt: Prove that given $c^Tx=d$ for all $x$ satisfying $Ax=b$ if and only if there is a vector $\lambda$, such that $c=A^T\lambda,d=b^T\lambda$. $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}, b\in \mathbb{R}^m, c\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

**My Attempt**

($\Rightarrow$)
For all $x$ satisfying both $c^Tx=d$ and $Ax=b$ means the hyperplane of $c^Tx=d$ is parallel and overlapping the set of hyperplanes defined in $Ax=b$. This if we scale each normal vector representing a hyperplane in A by $\frac{d}{b}=db^{-1}$, then we will recieve the normal vector $c$. If we let this scale vector equal to $\lambda = db^{-1}\Rightarrow d=b^T\lambda$ , then we have our results.

($\Leftarrow$) Given some vector $\lambda $ such that $c=A^T\lambda,d=b^T\lambda$. Then this point $\lambda$ exists on both the hyperplane $d=b^T\lambda$ and in the set of hyperplanes $c=A^T\lambda$..... thats all I really got

Any suggestions on if the $\Rightarrow$ is okay, and what I can do with the $\Leftarrow$?

Comment: Your first argument don't looks correct to me, i think that there are a better way to show it, i write below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer in a different way:

Suppose that there exists a $\lambda$ such that $c=A^T\lambda$, $d=b^T\lambda$. It is clear that if $Ax=b$ then $$c^Tx=\lambda^TAx=\lambda^Tb=d.$$
Conversely, suppose $Ax=b$ implies $c^Tx=d$, and that $\text{rank }A=r$. Let $F\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times(n−r)}$ be a matrix with $\mathcal{R}(F)=\mathcal{N}(A)$, and let $x_0$ be a solution of $Ax=b$. Then $Ax=b$ if and only if $x=Fy+x_0$ for some $y$, and $c^Tx=d$ for all $x=Fy+x_0$ implies $c^TFy+c^Tx_0=d$ for all $y$. This is only possible if $F^Tc=0$, i.e., $c\in\mathcal{N}(F^T)=\mathcal{R}(A^T)$, i.e., there exists a $\lambda$ such that $c=A^T\lambda$. The condition $c^TFy+c^Tx_0=d$ then reduces to $c^Tx_0=d$, i.e., $\lambda^TAx_0=\lambda^Tb=d$. In conclusion, if $c^Tx=d$ for all $x$ with $Ax=b$, then there there exists a $\lambda$ such that $c=A^T\lambda$ and $d=b^T\lambda$.